# OutOfMemory in .NET3.5 - Programmatic solution?

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-management, .net-3.5, out-of-memory

So, I know what it means. I know where the problem lays. But this is my problem. I have a control application running on a server that is managed by the system administrator and he refuses to upgrade from Windows Server 2003. Which means that I cannot upgrade from .NET Framework 3.5 to .NET Framework 4.5. Also the server is 32-bit.

My application is a 32-bit, multi-threaded and multi-purpose application. It interacts between our oracle database, track and trace database and others. The decision to keep the application as a one-in-all is a forced decision by the higher ups so that can't change currently.

It runs a couple of threads that don't really affect the memory, CPU or network much except for one procedure that splits up into several threads, which does the following.

It takes all the data from our oracle database with a couple of rules

```
[12:39:09] Tabel 'tsdsmd' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select tsdsmd.* from tsdsmd where dosvlg > 100044294 and dosvlg < 109999999'
[12:39:09] Tabel 'tsdnaw' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select tsdnaw.* from tsdnaw where dosvlg > 110017149 and dosvlg < 119999999'
[12:39:09] Tabel 'tstrac' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select tstrac.* from tstrac where irdvlg = 0 and tsacdt > = '2013-10-01' and ( ( tsacdt > '2013-10-01' ) or ( tsacty > '14:39:00' and tsacdt > = '2013-10-01' ) )'
[12:39:09] Tabel 'tslay4' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select tslay4.* from tslay4 where tsprda > '2013-10-02' or ( tsprda = '2013-10-02' and tsprti > '11:59:05' )'
[12:39:09] Tabel 'tsttks' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select tsttks.* from tsttks'
[12:39:09] Tabel 'tstrac' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select tstrac.* from tstrac where irdvlg = NULL and tsacdt > = '2013-05-06' and ( ( tsacdt > '2013-05-06' ) or ( tsacty > '18:55:00' and tsacdt = '2013-05-06' ) )'
[12:39:09] Tabel 'tsdnaw' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select tsdnaw.* from tsdnaw where dosvlg > 100044297 and dosvlg < 109999999'
[12:39:09] Tabel 'tsdsmd' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select tsdsmd.* from tsdsmd where dosvlg > 110017149 and dosvlg < 119999999'
[12:39:09] Tabel 'tsartc' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select tsartc.* from tsartc where rnropd <> 10003254 and rnropd <> 10004964 and rnropd <> 10005050 and rnropd <> 10005882 and rnropd <> 10006505 and rnropd <> 24232743'
[12:39:09] Tabel 'vrarst' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select vrarst.* from vrarst left outer join ( select * from tsarkm where tsarkm.tskenm = 3005 ) tsarkm3005 on vrarst.rnropd = tsarkm3005.rnropd and vrarst.artkd = tsarkm3005.artkd where tsarkm3005.tskenm = '' and ( rnropd = 10006584 or rnropd = 10001012 or rnropd = 10006634 or rnropd = 10006484 or rnropd = 10006296 or rnropd = 10025 or rnropd = 10002297 or rnropd = 10004544 or rnropd = 10006469 or rnropd = 29000000 or rnropd = 10001015 or rnropd = 10007544 or rnropd = 10007614 )'
[12:39:09] Tabel 'tstrac' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select tstrac.* from tstrac where irdvlg = 0 and tsacdt > = '2013-08-12' and ( ( tsacdt > '2013-08-12' ) or ( tsacty > '13:49:00' and tsacdt = '2013-08-12' ) )'
[12:39:09] Tabel 'tslay4' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select tslay4.* from tslay4 where tsprda > '2013-10-02' or ( tsprda = '2013-10-02' and tsprti > '12:23:32' )'
[12:39:09] Tabel 'tsttks' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select tsttks.* from tsttks'
[12:39:09] Tabel 'tstrac' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select tstrac.* from tstrac where irdvlg = NULL and tsacdt > = '2013-10-02' and ( ( tsacdt > '2013-10-02' ) or ( tsacty > '11:12:00' and tsacdt = '2013-10-02' ) )'
[12:39:09] [Environment02] Tabel 'tsdsmd' synchronisatie is niet gestart omdat deze niet aan staat voor deze tabel
[12:39:09] [Environment02] Tabel 'tsdsmd' synchronisatie is niet gestart omdat deze niet aan staat voor deze tabel
[12:39:09] [Environment02] Tabel 'tsdnaw' synchronisatie is niet gestart omdat deze niet aan staat voor deze tabel
[12:39:09] [Environment02] Tabel 'tsdnaw' synchronisatie is niet gestart omdat deze niet aan staat voor deze tabel
[12:39:09] Tabel 'vrfvrd' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select vrfvrd.* from vrfvrd where vrfilk = 1 and rnropd <> 10003254 and rnropd <> 10004964 and rnropd <> 10005050 and rnropd <> 10005882 and rnropd <> 10006505 and rnropd <> 24232743 and vrvrdt = 0'
[12:39:09] Tabel 'tsdsmd' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select tsdsmd.* from tsdsmd where dosvlg > 36910060 and dosvlg < 36999999'
[12:39:10] Tabel 'tsdsmd' synchronisatie is gestart, volgens de regel: 'Select tsdsmd.* from tsdsmd where dosvlg > 46504450 and dosvlg < 46699999'
```

To keep threads from running longer than 15 minutes each we've split some rules into two with a dynamic range that gets updated after it's finished it's current thread.

So what I've measured is that the network load is about 10 m/bit~ which is fine. The CPU load is optimized. It does a lot and doesn't strain the processor at all so the application isn't slowing down or stalling or anything like that.

The problem is that the application is 32-bit, runs windows server 2003 and .NET Framework 3.5. It has 4 GB of RAM. And the application generally uses up to 1.0 ~ 1.5 GB during this thread. Somewhere in that range the application throws the exception and prevents me from continuing the program even though I've tried to handle the exception by simply ending the threat but unfortunately the exception forces the application to quit (or in rare cases throw a break point error and then freezes.).

So upgrading .NET to 4.5 is out of the question, apparently.
I looked at the query rules and figured that I need ALL of the columns with *, which return a lot of data, so I can't lower the memory load there...

tl;dr: What can programmatic-ally do to make more efficient use out of available memory. Or how can I increase the memory this way?

Edit: Looks like I've found an issue with the application it itself. It is supposed to update the rules but for some reason the following rule isn't being updated:

```
'Select tstrac.* from tstrac where irdvlg = 0 and tsacdt > = '2013-08-12' and ( ( tsacdt > '2013-08-12' ) or ( tsacty > '13:49:00' and tsacdt = '2013-08-12' ) )'
```

And with each passing day all those track and trace messages keep adding up to the point where this query alone hogs up about 1,2 Gigs of memory. Regardless, the answers given here will be kept in mind as they've been insightful and helpful as well.

Comment: If it's a resource problem running it in parallel, can you run it sequentially?

Comment: Sequentially would probably solve the issue, I will have to test this. On a second thought, it would delay these records from being updated and customers would probably complain about it. Once records are set in our oracle database a series of triggers will occur such as track and trace status updates and other procedures within the database itself. Speed is rather essential for this thread.

Comment: Check what actual problem triggers the OutOfMemory Exception. Like real Resource Exhaustion (Memory, Handles etc.) or Memory Fragmentation or whatever. A Profiler might help at this point. When its clear what the actual problem you can do something aganist it. Just having an OutOfMemory Exception isn't enough to trigger the right action.

Answer (score 1):

Could the [3GB switch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823440) help here?

Comment: It is certainly worth a try!